# Why does not work two bind way in directive Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I use directive:

```
 return {
   restrict: 'E',
     scope: {
         isread: "=isread"
     ,....
     templateUrl: 'list.html',
```

Where list.html is:

```
<span ng-show="isread"></span>
```

And parent trmplate from where I call directive:

```
<div class="top-menu" ng-controller="NotificationController">
  <notification-list isread="is_read"></notification-list>
</div>
```

And `NotificationController`:

```
scope.makeRead = function() {
  $scope.is_read = true;
}
```

Why when I change  `$scope.is_read = true;` in controller it is not changed in directive in variable `isread`?

Comment: How do you checked in controller that `is_read` is updating to true?

Comment: By default it is: `$scope.is_read = false` in controller

Comment: Check whether  $scope.is_read  is updating to true in your controller

Comment: can you provide a fiddle to reproduce your problem ?

Comment: also how are you calling makeRead? Are you sure it is being called ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return {
 restrict: 'E',
 scope: {
     isread: "="
 ,....
 templateUrl: 'list.html',
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.